Karate-Gatling failed request is not marked as KO in the Gatling report
I'm using karate feature file to run gatling. There are some request having error status (400 403 500 504,...) but are not mark as KO in gatling report


I expect that gatling report should mark fail requests in feature file as Fail (KO). Btw, the gatling.log is just a part of running not all requests. How can I make the log full of requests?

Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? What is the build tool you are using? Stack?

Do you have a step for asserting the status code you expect if it is not 400, for example:
* status 200

Then Karate will mark the response as failed.

yes I have, and it's have error on log also, seems it's cannot get last request, due to i'm calling it from another feature file
* status 200
Cannot invoke "com.intuit.karate.http.Response.getStatus()" because "this.response" is null```

@kokochambo well, it sounds like a problem no one else has ever reported. I suggest providing a way to replicate this problem: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue
